# unable to access admin panel django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have changed my views and more specifically the request-mappings to "spring-like request mappings for djang". There for I had to change my urls to work as follows [link to Pypi documentation of spring-like request mappings for django](https://pypi.org/project/django-request-mapping/). After that change tho, Im unable to access admin panel, even tho I have it registered in my project urls.py.

Project urls.py:

```
from myapp.views import UserView
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = UrlPattern()

urlpatterns.register(UserView)

urlpatterns += [path('', include('myapp.urls'))]
urlpatterns += [path('admin/', admin.site.urls)]
```

Of course I have it imported in my settings, it used to work before that url refactoring I did. I just want to mention that I like this way of work and my question is specifically how do I fix the access to the admin panel, if it is possible ofc.

The error Im getting is:

> The current path, admin/, didn’t match any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from myapp.views import UserView
from django_request_mapping import UrlPattern
from django.contrib import admin

patterns = UrlPattern()

patterns.register(UserView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('<you url>', include(patterns.urls)),  # ------> Put your url here
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

alternatively, I think you can use DRF for this also instead of `django-request-mapping` because it seems like this module is not maintained anymore.

You can read more about it here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

and

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing